# Icon not showing on Notifications ( codename one )

Tags: mobile, codenameone

Icon not showing on Notifications (  codename one ). Here is the code:

```
 LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
 n.setId("demo-notification");
 n.setAlertBody("It's time to take a break and look at me");
 n.setAlertTitle("Break Time!");
 // alert sound file name must begin with notification_sound

 Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
    n,  
    System.currentTimeMillis(), 
    LocalNotification.REPEAT_MINUTE
 );
```

Comment: In which OS and version? I'm assuming Android. You need to place a 24x24 icon named `ic_stat_notify.png` under the `native/android` folder of the app. The icon can be white with transparency areas. The build server picks up this image and uses it as the notification icon if found on the project.